# Как удалить элемент из списка карт?

Tags: java, коллекции

У меня есть список карт `List<Map<String, Object>> data`. Мне нужно удалить из него объекты по ключу, и у меня совсем не получается.
Пробовал так: `data.removeIf(map -> map.containsKey("key"))`, но, видимо, я что-то делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, но у меня получается

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    map.put("test", "test value");
    data.add(map);

    System.out.println(data); //[{test=test value}]

    data.removeIf(item -> item.containsKey("test"));

    System.out.println(data);//[]
  }
```